# Express router use, but have an exception?

Tags: node.js, express, routes, http-status-code-404

So to render a custom 404 page on routes that don't exist I used this code.

```
// Custom 404 page
router.use(function(req, res) {
  res.render('404', {layout: false, title: '404: File Not Found'});
});
```

The problem is I am serving ghost as a child server and it renders on `/blog` and this conflicts with that, also I noticed this needs to be below all my other routes.

How do I render a custom 404 page without getting a conflict, is there a way to do something like `.use('/!blog')` is there a better way than `use()`?

Comment: Can you precisely describe your "child server" setup? Are these separate node processes, express sub-applications, etc?

Comment: ghost().then(function (ghostServer) {
    app.use(ghostServer.config.paths.subdir, ghostServer.rootApp);

    ghostServer.start(app); // runs ghost as child
});

Comment: https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/wiki/Using-Ghost-as-an-NPM-module

Comment: I cant completely describe the process because ghost handles most of it, but you can see from the configuration above that `ghostServer.start(app)` starts it as a child to my `app`

Comment: Looks like this explains it `Note: If you pass an express instance to ghostServer.start which has not had the Ghost rootApp mounted on it (i.e. you haven't called .use()), then ghostServer will still start a server but it will not have Ghost's functionality.` I think.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you just need to make sure your 404 middleware's `app.use` call executes after the `app.use` call for the ghost sub-app. You might just move the block in your question to inside the ghost `.then()` promise handler. That way ghost will answer it's requests and your 404 handler will only run if ghost ignores a request (because it doesn't start with the right path).

Comment: Okay makes sense, let me give it a try. I wonder though if it will conflict with my main routes, I will have to move the ghost block under my router initializing block.

Comment: It is still rendering the 404 page, `ghost().then(function (ghostServer) {
    app.use(ghostServer.config.paths.subdir, ghostServer.rootApp);

    ghostServer.start(app); // runs ghost as child

    // Custom 404 page
    router.use(function(req, res) {
      if(res.status(404)) {
        res.render('404', {layout: false, title: '404: File Not Found'});
       }
    });
    
});` I tried adding an if statement with res.status(400) and res.status(404), but with or without it still renders 404